# Wildcards in LIKE search is preventing trigram index from being used

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, indexing

I have an unexpected behavior where Postgres uses a Trigram index in one case and not the other. The only difference is searching for `LIKE 'NIKE'` vs `LIKE '%NIKE%'`.

1. Uses the index

   ```
   EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT * FROM "companies" WHERE (name LIKE 'NIKE');
                                                                   QUERY PLAN                                                                
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Index Scan using index_companies_on_name_hash on companies  (cost=0.00..8.02 rows=1 width=483) (actual time=2.598..2.599 rows=1 loops=1)
      Index Cond: ((name)::text = 'NIKE'::text)
      Filter: ((name)::text ~~ 'NIKE'::text)
      Buffers: shared read=3
      I/O Timings: read=1.543
    Planning:
      Buffers: shared hit=20
    Planning Time: 0.222 ms
    Execution Time: 2.636 ms
   (9 rows)
   ```
2. Does not use the index

   ```
   EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT * FROM "companies" WHERE (name LIKE '%NIKE%');
                                                              QUERY PLAN                                                           
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Gather  (cost=1000.00..161713.42 rows=248 width=483) (actual time=24.409..6687.109 rows=253 loops=1)
      Workers Planned: 2
      Workers Launched: 2
      Buffers: shared hit=1580 read=146187
      I/O Timings: read=18801.002
      ->  Parallel Seq Scan on companies  (cost=0.00..160688.62 rows=103 width=483) (actual time=80.824..6626.085 rows=84 loops=3)
            Filter: ((name)::text ~~ '%NIKE%'::text)
            Rows Removed by Filter: 826900
            Buffers: shared hit=1580 read=146187
            I/O Timings: read=18801.002
    Planning:
      Buffers: shared hit=47
    Planning Time: 3.536 ms
    Execution Time: 6687.635 ms
   (14 rows)
   ```

schema.rb

```
create_table "companies", force: :cascade do |t|
  ...
  t.index ["name"], name: "index_companies_on_name", opclass: :gin_trgm_ops, using: :gin
  t.index ["name"], name: "index_companies_on_name_hash", using: :hash     # For other use cases
end
```

Why is this occurring? I thought that Trigram indexes would be able to handle wildcards.

Second, how can I produce an index that will cover a wildcard search like #2?

---

#### Additional information:

```
postgres=> SELECT name, setting, unit FROM pg_settings WHERE name LIKE '%\_cost';
          name           | setting | unit 
-------------------------+---------+------
 cpu_index_tuple_cost    | 0.005   | 
 cpu_operator_cost       | 0.0025  | 
 cpu_tuple_cost          | 0.01    | 
 jit_above_cost          | 100000  | 
 jit_inline_above_cost   | 500000  | 
 jit_optimize_above_cost | 500000  | 
 parallel_setup_cost     | 1000    | 
 parallel_tuple_cost     | 0.1     | 
 random_page_cost        | 4       | 
 seq_page_cost           | 1       | 
(10 rows)
```

After `SET enable_seqscan = off;`:

```
postgres=> EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT * FROM "companies" WHERE (name LIKE '%NIKE%');
                                                           QUERY PLAN                                                            
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on companies  (cost=10000000000.00..10000178746.81 rows=248 width=454) (actual time=46.214..3637.287 rows=253 loops=1)
   Filter: ((name)::text ~~ '%NIKE%'::text)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 2480699
   Buffers: shared hit=3295 read=144476
   I/O Timings: read=3013.466
 Planning Time: 0.119 ms
 Execution Time: 3637.461 ms
(7 rows)
```

Comment: The trigram index supports that. But without `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output we cannot do more than guess what is going on.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I've added the information you requested. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. Strange, the row count estimates are quite good. Could you try `ANALYZE companies;` and see if that changes anything? Could you add the result of the following statement to the question: `SELECT name, setting, unit FROM pg_settings WHERE name LIKE '%\_cost';`? Also, it would be valuable to see the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for the slow statement after disabling sequential scans with `SET enable_seqscan = off;`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Running `ANALYZE companies;` takes #1 down to 1.0ms from 2.6ms and takes #2 from 6687ms to 6601ms. Not much change.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I've added the results to your other queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that the index is not used even if you set `enable_seqscan = off` proves that there is *no* valid trigram GIN index on `companies.name`.

Look at the result of

```
SELECT pg_get_indexdef('index_companies_on_name'::regclass);
```

and at `\d companies` using `psql`.

Comment: That's astonishing. Thank you very much.